# How to convert protocol-buffer message to a HashMap in java?

Tags: java, java-8, protocol-buffers

I have a protobuf message of the form

```
enum PolicyValidationType {
    Number = 0;
}


message NumberPolicyValidation {
    optional int64 maxValue = 1;
    optional int64 minValue = 2;
}

message PolicyObject {
    required string key = 1;
    optional string value = 2;
    optional string name = 3;
    optional PolicyValidationType validationType = 4;
    optional NumberPolicyValidation numberPolicyValidation = 5;
}
```

For example

```
policyObject {
      key: "sessionIdleTimeoutInSecs"
      value: "1800"
      name: "Session Idle Timeout"
      validationType: Number
      numberPolicyValidation {
        maxValue: 3600
        minValue: 5
      }
}
```

Can someone let me know how can I convert this to a `Map` like below:-

```
{validationType=Number, name=Session Idle Timeout, numberPolicyValidation={maxValue=3600.0, minValue=5.0}, value=1800, key=sessionIdleTimeoutInSecs}
```

One way I can think of is convert this to a json and then convert the json to map?

```
PolicyObject policyObject;
...
JsonFormat jsonFormat = new JsonFormat();
final String s = jsonFormat.printToString(policyObject);
Type objectMapType = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>() {}.getType();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(new TypeToken<HashMap<String,Object>>(){}.getType(), new PrimitiveDeserializer()).create();
Map<String, Object> mappedObject = gson.fromJson(s, objectMapType);
```

I think there must be some better way. Can someone suggest any better approach?

Answer (score 9):

I created small dedicated class to generically convert any Google protocol buffer message into a Java Map.

```
public class ProtoUtil {

@NotNull
public Map<String, Object> protoToMap(Message proto) {
    final Map<Descriptors.FieldDescriptor, Object> allFields = proto.getAllFields();
    Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<Descriptors.FieldDescriptor, Object> entry : allFields.entrySet()) {
        final Descriptors.FieldDescriptor fieldDescriptor = entry.getKey();
        final Object requestVal = entry.getValue();
        final Object mapVal = convertVal(proto, fieldDescriptor, requestVal);
        if (mapVal != null) {
            final String fieldName = fieldDescriptor.getName();
            map.put(fieldName, mapVal);
        }
    }
    return map;
}


@Nullable
/*package*/ Object convertVal(@NotNull Message proto, @NotNull Descriptors.FieldDescriptor fieldDescriptor, @Nullable Object protoVal) {
    Object result = null;
    if (protoVal != null) {
        if (fieldDescriptor.isRepeated()) {
            if (proto.getRepeatedFieldCount(fieldDescriptor) > 0) {
                final List originals = (List) protoVal;
                final List copies = new ArrayList(originals.size());
                for (Object original : originals) {
                    copies.add(convertAtomicVal(fieldDescriptor, original));
                }
                result = copies;
            }
        } else {
            result = convertAtomicVal(fieldDescriptor, protoVal);
        }
    }
    return result;
}


@Nullable
/*package*/ Object convertAtomicVal(@NotNull Descriptors.FieldDescriptor fieldDescriptor, @Nullable Object protoVal) {
    Object result = null;
    if (protoVal != null) {
        switch (fieldDescriptor.getJavaType()) {
            case INT:
            case LONG:
            case FLOAT:
            case DOUBLE:
            case BOOLEAN:
            case STRING:
                result = protoVal;
                break;
            case BYTE_STRING:
            case ENUM:
                result = protoVal.toString();
                break;
            case MESSAGE:
                result = protoToMap((Message) protoVal);
                break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}


}
```

Hope that helps!  Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that both approaches described above ([serialize/deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48821916/9531711) by [tuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/785523/tuk) and [custom converter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49480375/9531711) by [Zarnuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9549412/zarnuk)) will produce different outputs.

With the [serialize/deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48821916/9531711) approach:

1. Field names in snake_case format will be automatically converted into camelCase. `JsonFormat.printer()` does this.
2. Numeric values will be converted to float. `Gson` does that for you.
3. Values of type [Duration](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/google/protobuf/duration.proto) will be converted into strings with format durationInseconds + "s", i.e. "30s" for a duration of 30 seconds and "0.000500s" for a duration of 500,000 nanoseconds. `JsonFormat.printer()` does this.

With the [custom converter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49480375/9531711) approach:

1. Field names will remain as they are described on the proto file.
2. Integers and floats will keep their own type.
3. Values of type [Duration](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/google/protobuf/duration.proto) will become objects with their corresponding fields.

To show the differences, here is a comparison of the outcomes of both approaches.

**Original** message ([here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-proto/blob/master/grpc/service_config/service_config.proto) is the proto file):

```
method_config {
  name {
    service: "helloworld.Greeter"
    method: "SayHello"
  }
  retry_policy {
    max_attempts: 5
    initial_backoff {
      nanos: 500000
    }
    max_backoff {
      seconds: 30
    }
    backoff_multiplier: 2.0
    retryable_status_codes: UNAVAILABLE
  }
}
```

With the [serialize/deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48821916/9531711) approach:

```
{
   methodConfig=[ // field name was converted to cameCase
      {
         name=[
            {
               service=helloworld.Greeter,
               method=SayHello
            }
         ],
         retryPolicy={
            maxAttempts=5.0, // was integer originally
            initialBackoff=0.000500s, // was Duration originally
            maxBackoff=30s, // was Duration originally
            backoffMultiplier=2.0,
            retryableStatusCodes=[
               UNAVAILABLE
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

With the [custom converter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49480375/9531711) approach:

```
{
   method_config=[ // field names keep their snake_case format
      {
         name=[
            {
               service=helloworld.Greeter,
               method=SayHello
            }
         ],
         retry_policy={
            max_attempts=5, // Integers stay the same
            initial_backoff={ // Duration values remains an object
               nanos=500000
            },
            max_backoff={
               seconds=30
            },
            backoff_multiplier=2.0,
            retryable_status_codes=[
               UNAVAILABLE
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

**Bottom line**

So which approach is better?

Well, it depends on what you are trying to do with the `Map<String, ?>`. In my case, I was configuring a grpc client to be retriable, which is done via [ManagedChannelBuilder.defaultServiceConfig](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ManagedChannelBuilder.html#defaultServiceConfig-java.util.Map-) API. The API accepts a `Map<String, ?>` with [this](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/service_config.md#format) format.

After several trials and errors, I figured that the defaultServiceConfig API assumes you are using GSON, hence the [serialize/deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48821916/9531711) approach worked for me.

One more advantage of the [serialize/deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48821916/9531711) approach is that the `Map<String, ?>` can be easily converted back to the original protobuf value by serializing it back to json, then using the `JsonFormat.parser()` to obtain the protobuf object:

```
    ServiceConfig original;
    ...
    String asJson = JsonFormat.printer().print(original);
    Map<String, ?> asMap = new Gson().fromJson(asJson, Map.class);
    // Convert back to ServiceConfig
    String backToJson = new Gson().toJson(asMap);
    ServiceConfig.Builder builder = ServiceConfig.newBuilder();
    JsonFormat.parser().merge(backToJson, builder);
    ServiceConfig backToOriginal = builder.build();
```

... whereas the [custom converter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49480375/9531711) approach method doesn't have an easy way to convert back as you need to write a function to convert the map back to the original proto by navigating the tree.